# Laplace transform $y''''+37y''+36y=g(t)$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, convolution, harmonic-functions

Hey this problem is making me insane so have at it and let me know what I keep screwing up.

Express the solution of the initial value problem in terms of a convolution integral:

$$y''''+37y''+36y=g(t),\\
y(0)=4,\ y'(0)=y''(0)=y'''(0)=0.$$

I keep getting stuck after I apply Laplace transform to both sides and apply the initial conditions.
Here's what I got so far:

\begin{align}s^4L(y)-4s^3+37s^2L(y)-4s+36L(y)&=L(g)\\
L(y)&=\frac{L(g)+4s^3-4s}{(s^2+36)(s^2+1)}\end{align}

and this is where I'm confused on how/what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you share the work you have done so far and point out the areas you are unsure about, you are much more likely to get help. In general, people don't like having a homework problem posted and then being expected to just solve the whole thing for you.

Comment: done, thanks for the tip

Comment: What is $g(t)$?

Comment: You could possibly begin decomposing $\frac{L(g)+4s^3-4s}{(s^2+36)(s^2+1)}$  into partial fractions, though what confuses me is the $L(g)$is it given to you?